# Show the rule-based style in the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, table, style-manager

I need this for a university project and have been trying everything I could without success...

I had this shapefile from our region (LAZIO) where I could easily get out of it area values and from the IDs I was able to isolate the different kind of soil usages with the rule based style editor.

Now I need to work with the table to extrapolate aggregate various area values and other data (plantation type and such...).  I was thinking to export the table directly to Excel but the main problem now is my final step, I can't find a way to show in the attribute table the name of the rule based style and I need this to sort which area is from which layer when I'll export that so I can make some graphs...

any help in how to show the style name/id in the attribute table?

[image: named rule based style I need in the table]

[image: the table where I need to add a column with the style]

If not possible this way, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You're working with a vector layer which has a "**categorized**" symbology *(cusarp2010)*. if you want to see the rules on which the symbology is based you have to right-click on the layer in the layer panel then choose **properties / symbology** and you will see the rules that have been used. I suppose some of your *"codice"* values have been grouped to build your 5 classes.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between `rule` and `label` you have used for the display can be directly translated into expression in the Field calculator.

The expression would be like **CASE WHEN** `rule` **THEN** `label`.

[image]

Comment: um...probably I am badly mistaken the question

Comment: ok, no i think you understand it good despite my bad description... anyway to add to that: as i have imported my region file into qgis with the map and the data i have created the different rule based style like this (example rule: SOIL1) CODICE = '111' or '112' or ... ; to identify the regions by their ID and assigning them different colors, so don't have quite the rules as you showed... now i should need something like you said to call in the table the name of the style assigned to every specific code (in the example: at the row CODICE '111' i need a column that say Soil 1.

Comment: Thanks @Harlock  If you can find out the list of such combinations, `CASE WHEN "CODICE" = '111' OR  "CODICE" = '112' THEN` can be expandable by adding multiple `OR` functions. But, I understand it is painful.